# python sqlite - deleting selected records

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 in python to delete a selection of rows from a table. My attempt fails, but I can't work out why.

The sql query works ok, but I can't implement it within the python code.

I have a set of records that are moved from `current_table` to `archive_table` after a period of time.

I'd like to clean up the `current_table` by removing those rows that are in the `archive_table` (matched on `id`).

Intended SQL query:

```sql
DELETE FROM current_table  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM archive_table);
```

Attempted python code:

```py
import sqlite3

def clean_up(current_table, archive_table):
    db = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_db)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql_query_delete = '''DELETE FROM %s  WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM %s);''' % (current_table, archive_table)

    try:
        cursor.execute(sql_query_delete)
        db.commit()
        db.close()
    except:
        print("error deleting")
```

Comment: You can't work out why because you have caught and hidden the error message that would tell you why. Remove that pointless try/except and let Python tell you exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: then use of  param for sql object as table or column name is not  allowed   ..  could be you need  dinamic sql for this  (sql code based on string concat )

Comment: Try this `sql_query_delete = '''DELETE FROM %s WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM %s);''', [current_table, archive_table]`

Answer (score 0):

Now working. The database file was locked by another process. Removing the pointless try/except led me to the detailed error message.